# Как сделать такой элемент?

Tags: android

Вот, к примеру, есть поле "hellow":

[image]

При нажатии на это поле открываются вниз дополнительные поля (текст, кнопка и т.д.):

[image]

Как этот элемент называется?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void collapse(final View v) {
        final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

        Animation a = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                    Log.i("HEIGHT", v.getLayoutParams().height + "");
                    v.requestLayout();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // 1dp/ms
        a.setDuration(500);
        v.startAnimation(a);
    }

public static void expand(final View v) {
        v.measure(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final int targtetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

        v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation a = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                        ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        : (int) (targtetHeight * interpolatedTime);
                Log.i("HEIGHT", v.getLayoutParams().height + "");
                v.requestLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // 1dp/ms
        a.setDuration(500);
        a.reset();
        a.setStartOffset(0);
        a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        v.startAnimation(a);
        Log.i("HEIGHT", "START");
    }
```

При помощи этих двух функций можно "сворачивать" и "разворачивать" вью.  
Предварительно у леяута нужно выставить высоту в 0.

```
a.setDuration(500); //сюда вместо 500 можно вставить требуемое время анимации.
```

Comment: Проще ObjectAnimator заюзать, по-моему.

Answer (score 0):

Элемент называется "Spoiler", но вроде в android нету такого стандартного элемента (можно сделать самому или поискать в Инете).